# Digital Signature destroys PDF/A compliance

Tags: fonts, digital-signature, pdfa

I am using LaTeX to create a valid PDF/A file. This works fine and validates. When I digitally sign this file, however, using a government-provided service in my country, the added signature breaks PDF/A compliance. This is the message I get fromVeraPDF:

> Specification: ISO 19005-2:2011, Clause: 6.2.11.4, Test number: 1
> The font programs for all fonts used for rendering within a conforming file shall be embedded within that file, as defined in ISO 32000-1:2008, 9.9.    Failed
> 1 occurrences

```
PDFont  Subtype == "Type3" || Subtype == "Type0" || renderingMode == 3 || fontFile_size == 1    
root/document[0]/pages[74](1208 0 obj PDPage)/annots[5](1404 0 obj PDWidgetAnnot)/appearance[0]
(1408 0 obj PDContentStream)/operators[2]/xObject[0]/contentStream[0]
(1405 0 obj PDContentStream)/operators[90]/font[0](Helvetica-Bold)
```

All that is added (apart form the invisible part of the digital signature, I suppose) is the image of a seal, providing details for the signatory, date, etc. Where does "Helvetica-Bold" come into play (it's certainly not visible in the output), and more importantly, is there anything I can do  to prep my document in a way so as to keep compliant? Pre-embed Helvetica, as it were? (I am using a different set of fonts, which are of course embedded.)

Comment: Essentially you have to make the signing code PDF/A compatible. Yes, to a certain degree changing signature appearances after signing is possible but that usually results in some remarks about changes to the signed document which you most likely don't want. Alternatively, if you cannot change the way the signature appearance is generated, use invisible signatures.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over the signing process whatsoever: It's a complete black box, and I only control the file before I present it for signature. Also, I don't want to change appearance at all, I am happy as is, except for the fact that it no longer validates as PDF/A once it has been signed.

Comment: Well, in that case you should look for a black box supporting pdf/a ;)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately that (obvious) solution is not viable in my case. That said, you seem to be missing the point: The only compliance issue the signed file has is the use (or mere declaration of use, as there seem to be no trace of it in the output) of a non-embedded font (Helvetica in this case.). I'm almost certain there is a way for me to embed that font, even before signing the document. I have, of course, asked the signatory for advice as well.

Comment: If that black box signer is the program introducing the problem font, then that black box signer is the program that needs to be fixed (or pdf/a-enabled to start with). Even if you embed Helvetica beforehand, the black box code would have to reference your embedded font which is unlikely unless it is documented to do so. And i assume you have studied the documentation first.

Comment: What can I say? Case closed, as they actually fixed the whole issue within two days (which I find mildly impressive for a quasi-government agency.)

Comment: Indeed, that sounds really speedy ;)